# Find $(m,n)$ where $\sum\limits_{r=1}^n r = \sum\limits_{r=1}^m r^2$.

Tags: summation, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

I was intrigued to find that the sum of the first $10$ integers is equal to the sum of the first $5$ squares. I then tried looking for other similar cases, i.e. by consider the following problem:

> Find pairs of $(m,n)$ where $$\sum_{r=1}^n r = \sum_{r=1}^m r^2$$

Converting the summations to closed-form and rearranging gives 
$$3n(n+1)=m(m+1)(2m+1)$$ How would you go about solving this?

Using numerical methods and considering values for $m$ from $1$ up to $1000$ I found the following solutions: 
$$(m,n)=(1,1), (5,10), (6,13), (85,645)$$

Could there be more? Or are these the only ones? What other methods would you suggest to approach this problem?

Comment: Those are all the solutions: http://oeis.org/A053611

Comment: Also discussed viz. Eqs (5)-(8) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquarePyramidalNumber.html).

Comment: Nice find, Winther and J.G. – thanks! It would be nice to see one could proceed from the mathworld Equation (8) on the to the final solution and conclusion.

Comment: Useful ref from OEIS link: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X72900364?via%3Dihub

Answer (score 3):

A modern approach to this kind of problems:

From $3n(n + 1) = m(m+1)(2m + 1)$ we get:
$$y^2 + 18y = x^3 + 9x^2 + 18x,$$ where $y = 18n$ and $x = 6m$.

It suffices to find integral points on this curve. This is easily done with a computer algebra system.

Paste the following code into [this page](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) and press "Evaluate".

```
E = EllipticCurve([0, 9, 18, 18, 0])
for (x, y, z) in E.integral_points():
    if x % 6 == 0:
        print(x // 6, y // 18)
```

We get the output:

```
(-1, 0)
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(5, 10)
(6, 13)
(85, 645)
```

---

It would seem a bit unfair that I simply post a code without any explanation on how it works.

Since I don't want to jump into the details of elliptic curves, I will talk briefly from an algorithmic point of view.

The computation of integral points on an elliptic curve (over $\mathbb Q$, with a model over $\mathbb Z$) has two steps. The first step is to find a basis of the Mordell-Weil group, i.e. the group of $\mathbb Q$-rational points on the curve; and the second step is to find which linear combinations of these $\mathbb Q$-rational points give rise to integral points.

For the first step, there is no known algorithm which can do it for any elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$. However, powerful methods (mainly the descent methods + Heegner point method) have been developped, so that in "most cases" we can do this step with this or that method. These, I believe, were developped quite early, probably in the 1920's (except the Heegner point method).

For the second step, the key point is Baker's explicit bound on the integral points, known as [Baker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem). This was developped in the late 1960's.

However, while Baker's bounds are effective, they are by no means *efficient*, meaning that they are usually too large to be useful. The solution is the [LLL algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm), which will dramatically reduce the bounds of Baker, eventually to a practically small value. This algorithm is not available until the 1980's.

---

Therefore we see the value of the paper by Frinkelstein: it was published in 1972, when the last ingredient LLL was still unavailable...

It's amazing how science and technology changed our lives, and our mathematical researches...

Comment: This is a nice approach and reminds me of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3425107/631742)

Comment: Thanks – nice and informative answer! (+1)