# Is $1+{n\choose 2}+{n\choose 4}$ ever a power of two except for $n=1,2,3,4,5,10$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, circles, diophantine-equations

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtkIWDE36qU) 3Blue1Brown video the formula $F=1+{n\choose 2}+{n\choose 4}$ is used to count the maximum number of regions that $n$ chords can cut a circle. The famous Moser's circle problem goes as follows: When $n=1,2,3,4,5$ we get that the maximum number of regions that $n$ chords can cut a circle is $1,2,4,8,16$ (respectively), but when $n=6$ we unexpectedly get the number $31$. In the video, Grant explains why this is the case using Pascal's triangle and the formula $F=1+{n\choose 2}+{n\choose 4}$ where $F$ denotes the maximum number of regions that $n$ chords can cut a circle.
At the end of the video he conjectures that $1+{n\choose 2}+{n\choose 4}$ is not a power of two for all values of $n\neq 1,2,3,4,5,10$. He said he thinks it can be done using Diophantine equations, but he doesn't know how to do it. It goes with out saying that neither do I.

Comment: The conjecture states if $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}: 1+{n\choose 2}+{n\choose 4}=m^2 \ ?$

Comment: What about $n=36$ ? For $n=4$ , we have a perfect cube, but not a perfect square.

Comment: @StinkingBishop You're right, thank you! What would be even more clever if there exists a case where $m=n$.

Comment: And don't we have $2$ for $n=2$ ?

Comment: @StinkingBishop The full equation is $\frac{n^4-6n^3+23n^2-18n+24}{24}=m^2$ This gives the solutions of $m=\pm \frac{\sqrt{24+n^4-6n^3+23n^2-18n}}{2\sqrt{6}}$ such that $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Peter I confused power of two and perfect square. Fixed.

Comment: The expression is a perfect power (different from $1$) or $n=3,4,5,10,36$ and no other $n\le 10^8$

Comment: If $1$ is considered to be a power of $2$ , the conjecture is probably true.

Comment: Everyone talking about $m^2$ or $244^2$ or the like needs to reread the question.  We are talking about finding $2^m$... i.e. *powers of two* such as is found for the first several terms of the sequence ($2,4,8,16,\dots$*).  We are not talking about *square numbers* $m^2$.  Admittedly, this was only recently edited to say this explicitly and there was a typo, however from context it should have been clear as well if you were familiar with the original problem.

Comment: The conjecture is true upto $n=10^9$ (with the powers of $2$) , enough for me to be convinced that there is no more solution.

Comment: We can establish even a much better result : I checked when $f(n)-2^k$ is reducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$ (necessary for an integer solution) and for $9\le k\le 10^4$ , this is not the case. hence , another power of two of this form must exceed $2^{10^4}$ !

Comment: @JMoravitz That is because the question, in its original form, actually asked if $1+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}$ could be a _perfect square_. It is quite hard to keep up when the OP is moving the goalposts. I will delete my earlier comments and I didn't think it would be required to watch the 3B1B video in order to discern the true nature of the question.

Comment: Would this answer the question? [When is the number of areas obtained by cutting a circle with $n$ chords a power of $2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3442247)

Comment: @StinkingBishop the original problem is a classic example of "*seemingly obvious patterns don't necessarily hold true*" and is one of the most commonly cited examples of why "*find the next number in the sequence*" problems are awful.  Of course it is not required to watch the video.  It is merely required to have had a standard education.